# MVVMCross how to use with WPF (Windows)?

Tags: wpf, windows, windows-runtime, mvvmcross

How can I use it on WinRT (Windows 8) - I can't compile it. Can I use it also with "normal" Windows (WPF)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide some more details. What you have already tried? Where are you stuck? See also: [How to ask a question?](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't currently an mvvmcross port specifically for wpf - a couple of people have suggested building one, but the majority of users have so far requested more work on mobile platforms instead. There is a current console (win32) port and extending that towards WPF should be quite straight-forward.

Future development is now based around the Portable Library branch - see some info on http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/mvvmcross-vnext-portable-class.html and the code on https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/tree/vnext

For WinRT, the TwitterSearch example within the vNext branch is a good place to start - it should compile and work across all of MonoTouch, MonoDroid, WP7, WinRT and Console:

[image: The move to vNext]

If you find you can't compile then please log specific compiler error messages either here or to github issues.

Comment: Thank you. Now it is working. I will try to use it in WPF solution.

Comment: Good luck. If you hit PCL or mvvmcross issues then ask on here :)

Answer (score 0):

`MvvmCrossLibs\MvvmCrossLibs.sln` consists of many projects, requiring different runtimes to be installed to open properly (Mono Touch, Mono Droid, WP7). If you only need the library in WinRT, your best bet is to open `Cirrious\Cirrious.MvvmCross\Cirrious.MvvmCross.WinRT.csproj` directly and add the missing `Newtonsoft.JSON` package with NuGet (you'll need to save the automatically created `.sln` file before that). It should compile just fine after that, at keast it did for me. Now just reference the assembly in your Windows Store app project and start using it.

I don't have any previous experience with MVVMCross, but it doesn't look like it currently supports despktop WPF apps. I don't know how difficult it would be to create/compile such a version, though.